# Header location not working on server php tried

Tags: php, redirect

Hi friends am trying to redirect a page once user logged in by using heade location but its not working unable to understand why..

Here is code..

```
<?php include "config.php"; ?>
 <?php session_start(); 
   error_reporting(0);
  ini_set('display_errors', 0);
    if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
   header("Location: user_details.php");
   }
 ?>
```

Here is my html login with php

```
 <html>
    <head>
     </head>
       <body>
           <div id="form">
              <form action="" method="POST">
              <div class="login-block">
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Username" id="username" name="user"/>
        <input type="password" value="" placeholder="Password" id="password" name="pass"/>
        <button type="submit" id="btn" value="Login" name="login">Submit</button>
         <?php
            if(isset($_POST['login']))
               {
                  $username=$_POST['user'];
                  $password=$_POST['pass'];
                  $username=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$username);
                  $password=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$password);
                  $password=md5(mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$password));
                  $query="SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '{$username}' and password='{$password}'";
                  $select_user_query=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
                  if(!$select_user_query)
                       {
                          die("Connection failed".mysqli_error($conn));
                       }
                while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($select_user_query))
                    {
                       $db_user_id=$row['id'];
                       $_SESSION['username']=$row['username'];
                       $db_user_email=$row['email'];
                       $db_user_password=$row['password'];
                     }
                if($username ===  $_SESSION['username'] && $password ===$db_user_password)
                    {
                       header("location: titles.php");
                     }

                  else
                 {
                     echo "<p style='color:#FF7B81'> enter correct username and password <p>";
                  }
                }
         ?>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Can anyone help me how can I redirect. I have used the echo statement after the heade location only I have tried both 'L' and 'l' in Location

Comment: You can not have output to the browser before you redirect. You should also have an exit after the header redirect.

Comment: [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) won't work once output is started try using [Output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php)

Comment: @Rasclatt I want to redirect once the user gets logged in correct so after output only I can redirect

Comment: echo "<meta HTTP-EQUIV='REFRESH' content='0; url=user_details.php'>";

Comment: alternatively you can move the HTML to inside the `else` section. so that no output is started if `$_POST['login']` is set

Comment: @bansi then I cant show login form

Comment: checkout my answer @vickykumar

Comment: Also, don't use `md5()` for passwords. It's already compromised and should really only be used for things that only need low level of obfuscation. Look into `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`

Comment: you can use @Kaylined's answer with last part of html fixed and adding `session_start()` in the beginning.

Comment: sessu=ion start is in beggining in my code already

Answer (score 0):

This line will never work:

```
   header("location: titles.php");
```

as headers must be sent before any form of output. It's usually common practice to place the isset($_POST['submit']) above the HTML block, and assign vars you might want to put into the HTML for later use.

Try reformatting your code as such:

```
<?php
        if(isset($_POST['login']))
           {
              $username=$_POST['user'];
              $password=$_POST['pass'];
              $username=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$username);
              $password=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$password);
              $password=md5(mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$password));
              $query="SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '{$username}' and password='{$password}'";
              $select_user_query=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
              if(!$select_user_query)
                   {
                      die("Connection failed".mysqli_error($conn));
                   }
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($select_user_query))
                {
                   $db_user_id=$row['id'];
                   $_SESSION['username']=$row['username'];
                   $db_user_email=$row['email'];
                   $db_user_password=$row['password'];
                 }
            if($username ===  $_SESSION['username'] && $password ===$db_user_password)
                {
                   header("location: titles.php");
                 }

              else
             {
                 $error = "<p style='color:#FF7B81'> enter correct username and password <p>";
              }
            }
     ?>

<html>
<head>
 </head>
   <body>
       <div id="form">
          <form action="" method="POST">
          <div class="login-block">
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Username" id="username" name="user"/>
    <input type="password" value="" placeholder="Password" id="password" name="pass"/>
    <button type="submit" id="btn" value="Login" name="login">Submit</button>
<?PHP if(isset($error)){ echo $error; } ?>
</div>
```

You also need to call:

```
session_start()
```

before you can assign any session vars.

Comment: You're also using session randomly, you need to add session_start() before you can use session vars. I've edited to include that

Answer (score 0):

```
 <html>
    <head>
     </head>
       <body>
           <div id="form">
              <form action="" method="POST">
              <div class="login-block">
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Username" id="username" name="user"/>
        <input type="password" value="" placeholder="Password" id="password" name="pass"/>
        <button type="submit" id="btn" value="Login" name="login">Submit</button>
         <?php
            if(isset($_POST['login']))
               {
                  $username=$_POST['user'];
                  $password=$_POST['pass'];
                  $username=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$username);
                  $password=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$password);
                  $password=md5(mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$password));
                  $query="SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '{$username}' and password='{$password}'";
                  $select_user_query=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
                  if(!$select_user_query)
                       {
                          die("Connection failed".mysqli_error($conn));
                       }
                while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($select_user_query))
                    {
                       $db_user_id=$row['id'];
                       $_SESSION['username']=$row['username'];
                       $db_user_email=$row['email'];
                       $db_user_password=$row['password'];
                     }
                if($username ===  $_SESSION['username'] && $password ===$db_user_password)
                    {
                       //header("location: titles.php");
                   echo "<script>window.location.href='titles.php'</script>";
                     }

                  else
                 {
                     echo "<p style='color:#FF7B81'> enter correct username and password <p>";
                  }
                }
         ?>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

> Try This

You have to start object.

```
// Add this start of file after <?php
ob_start();
```

Comment: there is lot more to output buffering than just `ob_start()`

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!